# Software center from kubuntu

Tags: 12.04, software-center, kubuntu, official-repositories

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the “pysdm” package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237066/where-is-the-pysdm-package)

I was trying to install pysdm on my kubuntu when i saw that i couldnt found it in software center, but in ubuntu software center it is.

Shouldnt kubuntu have repositories from ubuntu, it is in ubuntu's family?

If no, how can i get ubuntu repository in kubuntu software center?

***It is no duplicate since "pysdm" is just an example, there are many software that are missing from muon software center and exist in ubuntu software center.***

***Thanks for the people that answered.***

***Wanted to know if why they are different since they share repositories(or maybe they don't share repositories and I am mistaken).***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muon Software Center is (not yet at least) an all-purposes package manager: it's mainly meant to explore and easily install full applications, sort of avoiding the view of the thousands of dependencies and libraries included in the repositories.

If you try to search for any `lib*` package in Muon Software Center, even when you type the full name of a package in the repository, it will not find it.
Ubuntu Software Center, on the other hand, has this capability.
I guess that Muon Software Center only selects a range of applications to include and search through.

So if you want to install a specific package (even when an application) you're safer by using Muon Package Manager instead, which is the equivalent of Synaptic shipped by default on Kubuntu, or `sudo apt-get install` as already suggested.

Comment: the point of the software center is to be able to find a software to install without the sudo apt-get install cause you cannot know the package name on all softwares and trying to find out the name of the package so you can install it everytime u need it, its a waste of time.also thank you for your response

Comment: Muon is quite disapointing, switched to ubuntu software center since has more utiliy.Finding and installing everything i need and updates homerun launcher with newest applications installed.

Comment: Ubuntu's software center managed to unify the idea of a software center as you describe it (install a program without needing to find the name of the package) and a "old-style" package manager.
Muon is not quite there yet - and maybe doesn't plan to be.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to installing it from the Synaptic Package Manager?

It is showing up for me both in the Ubuntu Software center and the Synaptic Package manager.
You should also be able to install it from the command line `sudo apt-get install pysdm`

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gogogeekboy.com/2012/07/installing-ubuntu-software-center-kubuntu-12-04/ i did some digging around when i decided to scrap ubuntu12.10 and go back to 12.04 and after deciding to give kubuntu a shot as well, getting the games etc i want was one of my first questions. i haventtried the reccomendations on the siote yet as i havent actually installed kubuntu and am just running a live usb to try it ou but the above might work

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.